# Change Drupal username when auto creating using tags

Tags: civicrm-entity, tags, drupal-rules, user

I'm using Pete's [great way of creating Drupal users by adding a tag](https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms), but was wondering (as Michael McAndrew did in the comments on that page) how a different username could be auto-created, e.g. email address or even firstnamelastname. (Presumably the Rule would fail if a duplicate username occurred?)

And bonus question: on the same page Coleman mentioned potentially using Rules to remove the tag and clean up, but I can't work out which action this would be under. Any pointers?

Comment: Have you had any luck figuring this one out? thanks\

Comment: I used the patch in the answer. It failed on application, so I had to manually apply, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [unreviewed patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2271487) to the CiviCRM Entity module that tackles this.

To clean up and remove a tag, you can easily set up CiviRules to just delete a tag as soon as it's created.

Comment: have you tested it and marked it as 'reviewed by community' to help push it along?

Comment: Haven't had time to test it yet!